# How do I make a Windows-style cls script for Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, screen

How do I make a cls-type command for Ubuntu/Linux that will not only clear the terminal emulator screen, but also make it so you can't scroll up to see the stuff you cleared? Note that the `clear` command does not eliminate the text. It just scrolls it up out of view. Also, any information about setting it up as a system-wide command, called `cls` would be helpful (especially nice for Windows users coming to Linux).

Comment: Ah, I was actually just asking it to post an answer similar to user207900's. It's a very, very similar question (and I didn't know of the other question when I asked or answered it), but my question did ask about creating a script to do it (rather than just a command-line command). I plan to update my answer with an explanation of update-alternatives. I'll update the question a little, too.

Comment: Even if we close this as a duplicate, your answer can be merged into the master question. So don't worry--and by all means, if you wish to continue expanding/improving your answer, please do so! (Btw, welcome to Ask Ubuntu!)

Comment: Thanks! :) I added the updates I referenced (and upvoted user207900's answer to help it gain more attention).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by @user2962794, The command to clear the terminal is issuing the escape code `\033c`. This is the VT-100 ANSI escape sequence for resetting the terminal to its initial state (RIS, see [here](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php)) and is an ASCII "Escape" character (`\033`) followed by a `c`.

Therefore, to clear your terminal, all you need is one of

```
printf printf "\033c"
```

or

```
echo -ne "\033c"
```

To make that simpler, you can create an alias for it. Add this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias cls="printf '\033c'"
```

Now, open a new terminal and running `cls` will clear it. Note that if there already is a command named `cls`, this will supersede it. Make sure you choose a name that is unique to avoid this.

Comment: Is there a system-wide (all users) version of `.nashrc`?

Comment: @user2962794 first of all, that was a typo, it should have been `.bashrc` not `.nashrc` (I've now corrected it). Anyway, the system-wide one is `/etc/bash.bashrc` for all users whose shell is bash.

Answer (score 2):

Make a script, name it `cls`, make it executable (`chmod +x cls`), and give it these contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "\033c"
```

Before you add it to your path, you may want to make sure there are no programs called `cls` already:

```
update-alternatives --config cls
```

Then, to add it to your path system-wide, put your script in a safe system location, such as `/opt/bin/cls` and use `update-alternatives` to add it to the path for all users:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cls cls /opt/bin/cls 0
```

You can place your script in `~/bin` (the tilde stands for your home directory) for it to be in a single user's path (if you had to create the `bin` directory, you'll need to restart your computer before it will be in your path. There's no need to do anything with update-alternatives in this case.

Comment: Will `update-alternatives --config cls` effectively check for other `cls`es if they're present but don't use the alternatives system?

Comment: I don't believe it would. I know it won't check the contents of `~/bin`.

Comment: I don't see the point of the `update-alternatives` approach. If there is another `cls` command in the OP's path, there is no reason to expect it to be in the alternatives system.